# CSS: text-background:hide-other-text;

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have multiple texts over each other and yet only one of them readable/visible, without setting the background-color of the text container of the desired readable one ?

I dream about something like:

```
text-background: hide-other-text;
```

more info:
I need the background color of the elements behind the text, and text "below" needs to go up to the text on top.

Comment: Just overlay elements and hide using either display none or a z index higher than others

Comment: **CSS** `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`?:

Comment: I can honestly say that I don't believe that property will *ever* make it into any finalised CSS spec, the use-case seems way too limited.

Comment: When do you wan't text on text - it's unreadable ? "text-background: hide-other-text;" sould be default.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to hide the one piece of text, and add the other piece of text, if you so desired. That might be much simpler in this case.